# find a file inside application documents directory

Tags: ios, swift

i have copied a video file inside my installed application documents directory using iexplorer and i am trying to play it on avplayer by accessing the video.but i cant found the video.here is my code to find the files under application documents directoy

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory: String = paths[0] as! String
    do {
    let filePathsArray: [AnyObject] = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory)
    print("files array %@", filePathsArray)
    }catch {

    }
```

it shows empty

Comment: if you are using static video file past oin Document directory then you can also past movie file in project and load it directlry :)

Answer (score 0):

from Apple Docs:

> *subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:*
>
> Performs a deep enumeration of the specified directory and returns
>      the paths of all of the contained **subdirectories**.

try iterating thru `.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error` instead